# How to display text coming from property with special character - adaptive cards

Tags: microsoft-teams, elastic-stack, adaptive-cards

I am trying to create an adaptive card for an elastic alert. The payload I receive for the card kind of looks like the following json:

```
{
    "hits": {
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "fields": {
                    "log.@m": 
                        "some log message"
                    ,
                    "kubernetes.node.name": [
                        "node name"
                    ],
                    "log.@l": [
                        "Error"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I, however, have some problems getting the fields into a TextBlock because of the dot notation or the .@ in the fields names. If I remove them (only possible in the adaptive card designer with the sample data editor) I can display the data just fine. It is not possible to change the property names since this is an Elastic thing.

I tried a lot of possibilities for the text field.

- through the UI editor
- using [] brackets
- using single quotes
- combinations of the above...

  ```
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "$when": "${$index < 2}",
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "${log.m}",
                "$data": "${fields}"
            }
        ],
        "$data": "${$root.hits.hits}"
    }
  ```

Does anyone have an idea how I could go about displaying the fields in a textblock?

Comment: Please have look into this Adaptive card sample-https://adaptivecards.io/samples/

Comment: It doesn't say how I should handle displaying properties with a . (dot) in its name.